# Dividing the screen in four blocks

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, angular-ui-bootstrap

My goal is to break my screen in four different blocks that are not the same size, just like in the picture (block one and two should be the same size). I tried using bootstrap which kinda works but it makes it scrollable and I want to avoid that. Is there a way to make it not scrollable and have each block in a fixed size? Any tips would be appreciated. I'm using bootstrap and angularjs. [image]

This is what I have so far, but I want to make full screen. 
https://codepen.io/BrunoTrax/pen/XWWVNgL

```
<style>
    .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: [col1-start] 100px  [col2-start] 100px  [col3-start] 100px [col3-end];
        grid-template-rows: [row1-start] auto [row2-start] auto [row2-end];
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
      }

      .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 150%;
      }

      .a {
        grid-column: col1-start / col3-start;
        grid-row: row2-start ;
      }
      .b {
        grid-column: col3-start ;
        grid-row: row1-start / row2-end;
      }
      .c {
        grid-column: col1-start;
        grid-row: row1-start ;
      }
      .d {
        grid-column: col2-start ;
        grid-row: row1-start ;
      }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out CSS "Grid's". Basically, you can declare a grid inside your css and use the `grid-template-columns` property to display your blocks in various arrangements. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/look-ma-no-media-queries-responsive-layouts-using-css-grid/) is a good resource that shows you how to create a custom layout.

The grid property also allows you to declare a height and width which will fix your scrolling problem.

Check this out and start experamenting.

CSS

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  grid-template-areas: "head head"
                       "nav  main"
                       "nav  foot";
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 30px;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
}

.grid > header {
  grid-area: head;
  background: #eee;
}

.grid > navLeft {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: #a072;
}

.grid > main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #8510ff;
}

.grid > footer {
  grid-area: foot;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
}
```

HTML

````
  <header> Hello</header>
  <navLeft> Hello</navLeft>
  <main> Hello</main>
  <p> Hello</p>
  <p> Hello</p>
</div> ```
````

Comment: Can you double check the code? Its missing the first declaration on the css.

Comment: Sorry it got cut off. Fixed.

Comment: @bhazero025 Have you figured out how to size the grid elements to fullscreen?